# Can 401(a) "FICA Alternative" plan be rolled over into Roth IRA?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, rollover

My employer uses a 401(a) plan, or "FICA Alternative" to Social Security. Every quarter I get a statement of my balance, which has grown quite a bit. I'm wondering, can this 401(a) balance ever be rolled over into a Roth IRA? I have no prior experience with Social Security alternatives like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's what the IRS says](http://www.irs.gov/irb/2009-39_IRB/ar15.html) on this topic.  I provide no interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

The plan is similar to other retirement plans and a conversion to Roth is allowed. But keep in mind, your employer may not offer the Roth, and not allow you to transfer the funds away from their administrator. 
You should have a contact for your retirement plan that give you clear direction on what's permitted.

Edit - On re-reading it appears I misunderstood a bit. The account can be converted to an IRA after separation from your employer (the government, correct?). 
As I understand the 401(a), it may contain post tax money as well as pre-tax. The pretax money should roll to a traditional IRA, the post-tax, to Roth.

Comment: Right you are, regarding the specific terms of the retirement plan. In the U.S., for certain city and state jobs, there are 401(a)'s, 403(b)'s and more that I don't recall now. It is essential to talk to one's plan administrator and ask whether a Roth or other type of retirement account offered, and similarly, if early withdrawal is ever allowed, and under what terms.

Answer (score 0):

Having retired some time ago
from a state government job in which I paid into a retirement plan in lieu of Social Security and Medicare taxes (post-1986 hirees were required
to pay Medicare tax but it was optional for pre-1986 hirees), I concur with JoeTaxpayer's and Feral Oink's recommendations that you talk to your plan
administrators.  My retirement choices were

- A. Accept a joint-and-survivor annuity based on the total amount contributed 
  plus interest at x% per annum deemed to have been earned on the contributions.
  The actuarial table used to calculate the annuity amount is determined by the
  state.
  Accepting this choice also allowed continued participation in the State health
  insurance program for both retiree and spouse.

or

- B. Take a lump-sum settlement which could be rolled over into a Traditional
  IRA (which could later be converted to a Roth IRA after paying the taxes
  due, etc) or used to purchase a single-premium annuity from an insurance company
  of my choice if I wished to do so. **However**, the lump sum would be computed 
  by adding interest at the rate of essentially (x/2)% on the contributions. 
  Also, taking a lump sum meant that participation in the State health insurance
  program was not permissible.  Because of the hit on the interest calculation,
  the lump sum turned out to be quite a bit smaller than the amount needed
  to purchase a comparable annuity from an insurance company.  My plan
  administrator told me that very few people opted for Plan B. I am told
  that because of the State's precarious financial condition, more
  people are opting for Plan B in order to get their money while the
  going is good.

Essentially the same option was offered people who resigned and left
State employment before retirement age. They could leave the money in
the retirement system and start collecting their annuity upon reaching
retirement age, or take a much reduced lump-sum settlement and don't
the swinging door hit you on the back on the way out.

So, before opting to roll over that money into an IRA, be sure
to understand the plan details and how lump-sum settlements are
treated versus taking an annuity payment.

As a final comment, State retirees who have not paid FICA taxes
are, of course, not eligible to receive Social Security benefits
based on this employment. If they are eligible for SS benefits 
based on other employment (e.g. previous employment, or self-employment
income), **these** benefits are reduced.  Furthermore, they are 
not entitled to get spousal SS benefits (or at best, they get
greatly reduced benefits) from the FICA-covered employment of their spouse.
Read about the Windfall Elimination Provision and
the Government Pensions Offset Provision. If a lump-sum
settlement is taken, the Social Security Administration
uses the annuity purchasable with that amount as the 
pension that you are getting.